# updateOne does not catch error. How can I catch errors?

Tags: mongodb

I am learning how to use MongoDB, as so I am running small codes to catch the peculiarities of MongoDB. 
I am testing the following code:

```
const listOfMovies = ["Nightmare on Elm Street", "Saw", "Batman", SpiderMan];
  collection
    .updateOne(
      { genre: "horror" },
      {
        $push: {
          top10: { $each: listOfMovies, $slice: -2 }
        }
      }
    )
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`we inserted!`);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("something went wrong");
    });
```

See that SpiderMan is not a string, I wanted to simulate an error, but nothing is printed out as I expected. If I make it properly (i.e., "SpiderMan"), it saves and prints out the successful message.
Anyone knows how I can make sure any error like this one is caught?

Comment: If `SpriderMan` is not a string then it must be a variable or else there will be an error like this: `ReferenceError: SpiderMan is not defined`.

Comment: it is not a variable! I do not define anywhere, unless this is one the weird things of JavaScript, it is defined somehow automatically. Nonetheless, shouldn't the error appear on catch? I am just printing out the error.

Comment: It is a syntax error. The code will not run (with the error). So, the `catch` will run only when your program runs.

Comment: Thanks, now I think I get it! It is one of the stranges things of JavaScripts, it does not complain, but the code does not run properly.